# Empty image auto generated when using ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture(). Android Kotlin

Tags: android, android-intent, mediastore

I want to use system camera to take photos and save to external storage. Here is what I've done.

```
val dUri = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 28) {
        MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY)
    } else {
        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
    }

val fileName = "ride_map-camera-${System.currentTimeMillis()}.jpg"
val newImageDetails = ContentValues().apply {
        put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName)
        put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg")
    }
val newUri = context.contentResolver.insert(dUri,newImageDetails)

val cameraLauncher =
    rememberLauncherForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture()) { it: Boolean ->
}

Button(
    modifier = Modifier.size(90.dp, 60.dp),
    onClick = {
        val permissionCheckResult = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
        if (permissionCheckResult == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            cameraLauncher.launch(newUri)
        } else {
            permissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
        }
    }
) {
    Icon(painter = painterResource(
        id = R.drawable.camera),
        contentDescription = null,
        tint = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.tertiary
    )
}
```

Problem is
Latest image will replace the former one. It only saves one image.
It saves empty image if I open the camera without taking a photo or dismiss the photo. The empty image has 0KB size and -1*-1 dimension.

The first problem is fixed. It seems inevitable that an empty file will be saved. How can i delete it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is fixed.
Just create a temp file to save the result of takePicture. If it returns ture then save the temp file to gallery.
Or you can delete the empty file when it returns false.